# django and axios: how to enable CORS for OPTIONS

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I am using axios for doing a `POST` request in my reactjs page.

```
  const url = "test/";
  const data = {
    email: "test@test.com",
    password: "test",
  };
  const headers = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  axios.post(url, data, headers)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

In my Django I have

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS =  True
```

and my axios request works fine.

But  now in my Django view(which corresponds to the url)  I have intentionally put a wrong python statement.

i.e

```
def test(request):
   a+=1
   ..... return some json
```

**If I dont put a+=1 then the axios works fine, without any error

And when run the axios code i get

[image]

and also

[image]

In my Django console i see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.........
  ........../views.py", line 139, in test
    a+=1
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

But generally if I am not using rest api, Django shows the traceback html when anything wrong happens in the browser itself.

Even with ajax i can see the response in the developertools.

But with axios its not showing

I checked with postman it shows the traceback

[image]

Can someone help how to achieve this. I want to capture the traceback also in the script